# SQlite saves certain things as Sci Notation

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I have a prog that stores data in a sqlite db.  Among other tables in the db, I have one created as follows:

```
 conn.execute("CREATE TABLE {tn} ({cn} {ct})".format(tn=test, cn="STEP_NAME", ct="TEXT"))
```

Therein, the table creates has several columns.  One is:

```
conn.execute("ALTER TABLE {tn} ADD COLUMN '{cn}' {ct} ".format(tn=test, cn=value, ct="TEXT"))
```

Im trying to save data to it, but it's behaving in a way I can't explain.  When I save 270113185308874890 to it, it appears 270113185308874890 when recalled.  However, when I save 89014103258771944209 to it, it saves as 8.90141032588e+19.

How can I prevent this?  I've tried different column types with no luck and really don't understand why it's converting it.

EDIT:

Code that I'm using to store it

```
def store_result(conn, table_name, row_name, data):
    for k, v in data.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, str):
            data[k] = v.replace('"', "'").rstrip(' \t\r\n\0')
    keys = data.keys()
    vals = data.values()
    # add test name column for everything but info call
    if table_name != "info":
        keys.insert(0, "STEP_NAME")
        vals.insert(0, str(row_name))
    # Make pretty for sqlite3 and its crazy param rules.
    sql_keys = ','.join(str(v) for v in keys)
    sql_vals = ','.join(str(v) for v in [x if str.isdigit(str(x)) else '"{}"'.format(x) for x in vals])
    # try to write or tell me why not.
    try:
        conn.execute("""INSERT into {table}({sql_keys}) values ({vals})""".format(table=table_name,
                                                                                  sql_keys=sql_keys,
                                                                                  vals=sql_vals))
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warn("DB ERROR:{}_{}_{}".format(e, table_name, row_name))
```

Comment: Can you include the code that inserts the two numbers into the database?

Answer (score 0):

When you print the values after they are returned from the table, the type of the variable that holds the values affects both how they're printed and they're precision. As an example:

```
int1 = 270113185308874890;
float1 = 270113185308874890.0;

int2 = 89014103258771944209;
float2 = 89014103258771944209.0;

print 'int1  : ' + str(int1);
print 'float1: ' + str(float1);

print '';

print 'int2  : ' + str(int2);
print 'float2: ' + str(float2);
```

Will print:

```
int1  : 270113185308874890
float1: 2.70113185309e+17

int2  : 89014103258771944209
float2: 8.90141032588e+19
```

It seems likely that in the SQLite table the type is TEXT, as shown in the example from the SQLite website (https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) below. You should use the typeof() function to ensure that you're data is being stored as TEXT.

Finally, you should consider using the INTEGER type rather than TEXT in your SQLite table if all of your numbers will be integers. Also if you are using TEXT to try and preserve precision, make sure you are not limited by the calling code. I.e. unless you are dealing with the Decimal Python type the REAL SQLite type will match the precision of the Float Python type.

> 2.3 Column Affinity Behavior Example
>
> The following SQL demonstrates how SQLite uses column affinity to do
>   type conversions when values are inserted into a table.
>
> CREATE TABLE t1(
>       **t  TEXT**,     -- text affinity by rule 2
>       nu NUMERIC,  -- numeric affinity by rule 5
>       i  INTEGER,  -- integer affinity by rule 1
>       r  REAL,     -- real affinity by rule 4
>       no BLOB      -- no affinity by rule 3 );
>
> -- Values stored as **TEXT**, INTEGER, INTEGER, REAL, TEXT.
>
> > INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(**'500.0'**, '500.0', '500.0', '500.0', '500.0');
> >     SELECT typeof(t), typeof(nu), typeof(i), typeof(r), typeof(no) FROM t1;
> >     **text**|integer|integer|real|text
>
> -- Values stored as **TEXT**, INTEGER, INTEGER, REAL, REAL.
>
> > DELETE FROM t1;
> >     INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(**500.0**, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0);
> >     SELECT typeof(t), typeof(nu), typeof(i), typeof(r), typeof(no) FROM t1;
> >     **text**|integer|integer|real|real
>
> -- Values stored as **TEXT**, INTEGER, INTEGER, REAL, INTEGER.
>
> > DELETE FROM t1;
> >     INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(**500**, 500, 500, 500, 500);
> >     SELECT typeof(t), typeof(nu), typeof(i), typeof(r), typeof(no) FROM t1;
> >     **text**|integer|integer|real|integer